# Node.JS subscribing to a channel on a given IP

Tags: node.js, redis

Scenario: PHP app that publishes to redis channel called "message" **sitting on IP 1.2.3.4**

How to connect from node to that channel **on that IP**?

```
var listener = redis.createClient();
listener.subscribe('message', /* ? '1.2.3.4' ? */);

listener.on("messages", function(channel, message) {
  // do something with data
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). You can specify the host you are using:

```
redis.createClient(port, host, options)
---
Create a new client connection. 
port defaults to 6379 and host defaults to 127.0.0.1.
```

So you should use:

```
redis.createClient('1.2.3.4');
```

It is in the documentation which is pretty good and I think you should read it completely.

**P.S:** When you make redis available for remote host(s) I think you should have your firewall setup properly to deny access from other IPs(whitelist).